# Grouping dataframe but mean function is not running

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, group

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Downloads Tab\Flavors.csv")
df

group_by_frame = df.groupby('Base Flavor')
group_by_frame.mean()
```

- THIS LINE HERE IS NOT RUNNING
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEMt0.png)

The video I'm following shows the exact same syntax and is functioning properly.

Tried restarting but did not make any changes to the syntax

Comment: What version of pandas are you using

Comment: Try with numeric_only. group_by_frame.mean(numberic_only=True)

Comment: use `group_by_frame.mean(numeric_only=True)`. and read linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233716/groupby-mean-not-working-on-titanic-dataset-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the full error as text, not image. Additionally, provided the csv_read part functions as you expect, rather skip it as post an input data such as print(df). See [ask] and [mre]